# preventing jquery .click from stacking on lists

Tags: jquery, events

I have a list of divs I'm using as links in jQuery.  Clicking on one will fadeIn a content panel.  What I'm trying to accomplish is making it so you can't keep clicking on each one causing the panels to stack and fadeIn and fadeOut in series.  I want all other click to fail until the current action finishes.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-row">
    <ul>
        <li><div class="btn-nav" pane="home">Home</div></li>
        <li><div class="btn-nav" pane="experience">Experience</div></li>
        <li><div class="btn-nav" pane="skills">Skills</div></li>
        <li><div class="btn-nav" pane="links">Links</div></li>
        <li><div class="btn-nav" pane="contact">Contact Me</div></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container home">
    Home
</div>
<div class="container experience">
    Experience
</div>
<div class="container skills">
    Skills
</div>
<div class="container links">
    Links
</div>
<div class="container contact">
    Contact
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".btn-nav").click(function(){
    var pane = $(this).attr("pane");
    $(".container").fadeOut(600);
    $(".container."+pane).delay(605).fadeIn(600);
});
```

Comment: The keywords you're looking for are "jquery stop animation queue buildup". Checkout http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

Comment: I use the stop on hover but doesn't seem to work for me on clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `:animated` selector which select all elements that are in the progress of an animation at the time the selector is run. Using this you can just return from the click handler.

Try this.

```
$(".btn-nav").click(function(){
    if($(".container:animated").length > 0)
        return;

    var pane = $(this).attr("pane");
    $(".container").fadeOut(600);
    $(".container."+pane).delay(605).fadeIn(600);
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this works just as I wanted. I tried a version of this but for some reason it didn't dawn on me to check the container for animation.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want one element to fade in after the previous one finished fading out, it's better to put that code in a callback than using `delay`. As to your actual question, I'd suggest using a simple true/false lock to prevent the code from being run twice:

```
var locked = false;
$(".btn-nav").click(function(){
    if ( locked )
        return;
    locked = true;
    var pane = $(this).attr("pane");
    $(".container").fadeOut(600, function() {
        // Will run after the fade out has completed
        $(".container."+pane).fadeIn(600, function() {
            // Will run after the fade in has completed
            locked = false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to prevent me from clicking on each of the other divs before the fades complete.